# Median statistics in application to wages

Tags: mean, interpretation, descriptive-statistics, median

I read an article in a newspaper about wage gap between men and women where it is written:

> The first problem can be easily illustrated by the example of Great Britain. The government obliged the company with staff of more than 250 people to publish by April data on the average and median salary gap. More than 30 companies have already stated that they have an average and a median gap of zero, which is statistically implausible. One company reported a median gap of 116%, which is impossible. So far, only sixteen companies have published the data.

Could someone clarify:

1. Why is median gap of 116% impossible?
2. Why are an average and a median gap of zero statistically implausible?

Comment: Can you cite or link to the article where you read this?

Comment: Question (1) is not possible to understand in a unique way because it depends on how the "116%" is measured.  That's why it's important to provide some background, such as the reference requested by @gung.

Comment: it is in russian and it does not clariify methodology of how 116% was gotten (i guess providing of the link will not help). https://www.vedomosti.ru/management/articles/2018/03/20/754264-zhenschini-menshe